# Laravel map continue

Tags: php, laravel

How I can in laravel map function continue loop?

I have code:

```
return collect($response->rows ?? [])->map(function (array $userRow) {
        if ($userRow[0] == 'Returning Visitor') {
            return [
                $userRow[1] => [
                    'type' => $userRow[0],
                    'sessions' => (int) $userRow[2],
                ]
            ];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
});
```

And output:

```
Collection {#986 ▼
   #items: array:4 [▼
     0 => false
     1 => false
     2 => array:1 [▶]
     3 => array:1 [▶]
    ]
}
```

I don't need params with `false`, I need continue it or delete. How I can resolve this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can add a [`reject` function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-reject) after the `map` to remove all values that are `false`.

```
return collect($response->rows ?? [])
    ->map(function (array $userRow) {
        if ($userRow[0] == 'Returning Visitor') {
            return [
                $userRow[1] => [
                    'type' => $userRow[0],
                    'sessions' => (int) $userRow[2],
                ]
            ];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })
    ->reject(function ($value) {
        return $value === false;
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `filter()` or `reject()` (inverse of filter) to filter your collection, then map as you need. Something like this:

```
return collect($response->rows ?? [])->filter(function (array $userRow) {
    return $userRow[0] == 'Returning Visitor';
})->map(function (array $userRow) {
    return [
        $userRow[1] => [
            'type'     => $userRow[0],
            'sessions' => (int) $userRow[2],
        ]
    ];
});
```